# (Teradata) Get a SUM value of previous 12 months, 3 months and 1 month

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query that I am using and I need to get a the value of the previous 12 months, 3 months and last month, yet do not know how to do it.

The current query I have is the following:

```sql
select top 100 
A.invoice_nbr
, A.invoice_date
, A.ship_from_dc_nbr
, A.ship_to_store_nbr
, A.trailer_id
, B.item_nbr
, C.old_nbr
, C.whpk_qty
, C.vnpk_qty
, C.item_type_code
, D.po_type
, SUM(B.each_ship_qty) as each_ship_qty
, SUM(B.variable_wt_qty) as variable_wt_qty
, SUM(B.ext_cost_amt) as ext_cost_amt
from DB.DC_INVOICE A
inner join DB.DC_INVOICE_LINE B ON A.invoice_nbr = B.invoice_nbr and A.invoice_date = B.invoice_date and A.ship_to_store_nbr = B.ship_to_store_nbr
inner join DB.item C on B.item_nbr = C.item_nbr
left join DB.purchase_order D on B.po_nbr = D.po_nbr
--where A.invoice_date = '2019-09-05' and A.ship_from_dc_nbr = 6011
group by 
A.invoice_nbr
, A.invoice_date
, A.ship_from_dc_nbr
, A.ship_to_store_nbr
, A.trailer_id
, B.item_nbr
, C.old_nbr
, C.whpk_qty
, C.vnpk_qty
, C.item_type_code
, D.po_type
```

I tried adding as another column the following for the "12 months" one:

```sql
(SELECT SUM(vnpk_qty)
    FROM DB.item C
    inner join DB.DC_INVOICE_LINE B ON B.item_nbr = C.item_nbr
    inner join DB.DC_INVOICE A ON A.invoice_nbr = B.invoice_nbr and A.ship_to_store_nbr = B.ship_to_store_nbr and BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, A.invoice_date,-365) AND  DATEADD(dd, A.invoice_date,-1)
    )
```

However that gave me the error:

```
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error: expected something between the 'and' keyword and the 'BETWEEN' keyword.
```

Any advice on how to get the data I am looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Past 12, 3, 1 month` based on what? Calendar date? Some sort of date in your data?  Sample data and desired results would help a lot here. The syntax error you are getting is because you need specify what is between - `A.ship_to_store_nbr = B.ship_to_store_nbr and <some column> BETWEEN ...`. Finally, dateadd is not a Teradata function.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your definition of "previous <n> months" is also needed.  Is that per row?  Is that relative to the current date?  Is that calendar months?

Comment: the field date is A.invoice_date, and previous "x months" is relative to current_date @Andrew

Comment: @gordonlinoff each row is an item, the previous would be from current date, sum of 12 previous month for that field

Comment: @lecarusin, in that case, Ravioli's conditional aggregation is the right basic approach. I still don't know if it's going to actually give you what you want (since we don't know what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation logic and the `ADD_MONTHS` function.  Here's the general idea:

```sql
SELECT 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN A.invoice_date > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12) THEN vnpk_qty END
  ) AS sum_12month,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN A.invoice_date > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -3) THEN vnpk_qty END
  ) AS sum_3month,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN A.invoice_date > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1) THEN vnpk_qty END
  ) AS sum_1month
FROM DB.DC_INVOICE A
```

So with your query, it would look like:

```sql
select top 100 
A.invoice_nbr
, A.invoice_date
, A.ship_from_dc_nbr
, A.ship_to_store_nbr
, A.trailer_id
, B.item_nbr
, C.old_nbr
, C.whpk_qty
, C.vnpk_qty
, C.item_type_code
, D.po_type
, SUM(B.each_ship_qty) as each_ship_qty
, SUM(B.variable_wt_qty) as variable_wt_qty
, SUM(B.ext_cost_amt) as ext_cost_amt
-- New fields
SUM(
  CASE WHEN A.invoice_date > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12) THEN C.vnpk_qty END
) AS sum_12month,
SUM(
  CASE WHEN A.invoice_date > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -3) THEN C.vnpk_qty END
) AS sum_3month,
SUM(
  CASE WHEN A.invoice_date > ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1) THEN C.vnpk_qty END
) AS sum_1month
-- End new fields
from DB.DC_INVOICE A
inner join DB.DC_INVOICE_LINE B ON A.invoice_nbr = B.invoice_nbr and A.invoice_date = B.invoice_date and A.ship_to_store_nbr = B.ship_to_store_nbr
inner join DB.item C on B.item_nbr = C.item_nbr
left join DB.purchase_order D on B.po_nbr = D.po_nbr
--where A.invoice_date = '2019-09-05' and A.ship_from_dc_nbr = 6011
group by 
A.invoice_nbr
, A.invoice_date
, A.ship_from_dc_nbr
, A.ship_to_store_nbr
, A.trailer_id
, B.item_nbr
, C.old_nbr
, C.whpk_qty
, C.vnpk_qty
, C.item_type_code
, D.po_type
```

You can adapt similar logic to your other `SUM()`s as needed.  It's still a normal `SUM` except you're choosing when to include a row's value in your calculation based on the `invoice_date`.

Comment: this would be all in one column or in 3 separated different one? Bit confused here

Comment: This would return a separate column for each `SUM()`.  See updated answer in a bit.

Comment: Any luck with this?  Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: yes it worked, thank you very much; sorry for late answer